# How to select a 1 class in a mutliple class with the same class name?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the structure:

```
<div class="features-image">
</div>
<div class="features-image">
</div>
<div class="features-image">
</div>
```

I've made a jQuery function that if the feature-image is in hover state something will happen.

My problem is that I have 3 featured-images, and the result when my mouse hovers the 1st featured-image, the 2nd and the 3rd will also get the same effect.

I want that if the 1st feature-image is in the hover state, the 2nd and 3rd will not copy the effect of the 1st image.

The code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('.features-image').hover(function(){ 
        jQuery(this).animate({
            top:'95px',
            h‌​eight:'135px'
        },500); 
    },function(){ 
        jQuery('.features-content').animate({
            top:'170px',
            height:'60px'
        },500);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Can you show your jQuery/hover code?

Comment: Don't post code to the comments, edit your original post so that we can see your code.

Comment: I've rolled back "Solved" in the title. Could you instead please (a) mark a given answer as accepted, or (b) provide your own solution as an answer and accept that?

Answer (score 1):

When you define something like a hover you use *this* to refer to the current element -

```
$('.features-image').hover(function() {
    $(this) // mouseover do stuff
}, function {
    $(this) // mouseout do stuff
});
```

Comment: Wasn't that what your question was? Or do you need to ask a different question?

Comment: My question is how to prevent other feature-image to copy the effect of feature-image that i choose to hover?

Comment: If you use $(this) it will only effect the current feature-image.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `this` pointer, which refers to the current div:

```
$(function(){

   $('.features-image').hover(function(){

         //do something with $(this), for example:

         $(this).stop(true, true).fadeIn(); //mouseover

   }, function(){

        $(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut(); //mouseout

   });

});
```

Comment: Actually my problem is i got multiple class name features-image so if i click anyone of the features-image all of them will have the same effect. all i want is if i click the 1st feature-image or anyone of them the others will not be affected

Comment: I fear that you're not explaining you question correctly. All of the samples here have answered your question. Maybe you should setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: @RjAyErmitzCortel And this is what you are asking for.